Propositional logic: Finding the maximum length of an implication chain
Particular definitions,

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language of a propositional logic.
For each sentence $\psi$ in $\mathcal{L}$, denote by $T_{\psi}$ the set of all
truth assignments $\mathfrak{U}: \mathcal{L} \rightarrow \{$true, false$\} $ s.t $\psi^{\mathfrak{U}}$ is true.

A sequence $\langle \psi_0, \dots, \psi_{l-1} \rangle$ of sentences in $\mathcal{L}$ is said to be an implication chain of length $\mathbf{l}$ if it satisfies $\forall j < l-1 : T_{\psi_j} \subsetneq T_{\psi_{j+1}}.$

The question is,

What is the maximum length of an implication chain if $|\mathcal{L}| = k?$

I understand the maximum length is at least $k$ however I struggle to understand if that is indeed the maximum and if so, then why. I'd like to have some ideas about it.
Thanks
(For the rest of the definitions - you can find those at Terence Tao blog at the following post: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/the-completeness-and-compactness-theorems-of-first-order-logic/)

What can you say about $T_{\psi_k}$ and $T_{\psi_{k+1}}$.  In particular, since these are sets, is either a proper subset of the other?  (Once you've included all the logic's possible sentences in your implication chain, there is nothing left with which you can extend the chain.)

@EricTowers Roughly speaking, the language is a set of atmoic formulas such as P,Q and the sentences are of the forms, say, P⟹Q, P∨Q, ¬P, etc. The precise definitions are fully presented at the blog's post which l've attached.

Yes.  Now what happens when you have all of them in a set and you try to add one more to that set?

@EricTowers I don't see its relevance since those are sentences

@EricTowers Any hint would be appreciated

Consider the case with only 2 propositional letters $p,q$. Then there are only 4 truth assignments. Why? So the best we can achieve is a sequence of length 5. Namely: no truth assignments, 1 truth assignment, $\dots$, all 4 truth assignments. Can we build an implication chain of this length? And then consider the general case with $k$.

@LéonProbst Thanks, so $k$ isn't the maximal?

No. Take for example k= 1, $\langle p \land \neg p, p , p\lor \neg p  \rangle$ is an implication chain of length 3.
